# how to accept the 'new friend requst' by submit button in html?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, form-submit

I'm trying to use submit button to accept the request, but I don't know how can I transfer the data to php file just by submit button;
Here is my web diagram

[image: web diagram]

Here is my code:

[image: Code]

Comment: Please copy and paste your code here.

Comment: really cute picture, now show us the real stuff

Comment: in any case, the question's too broad; try something and then post some real code with the one you had difficulties with. We're not going to write it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very helpful and your code is not very helpful but here might be a half solution.
under your `<form>` please name your submits like `name="yes" name="no"`
 EX: agree.php

```
<?PHP
  if(isset($_POST['yes']) && $_POST['yes'] == "yes") 
  {
    //Do Accepting Code Like Insert Into Database or W/E
  }
  elseif(isset($_POST['no']) && $_POST['no'] == "no")
  {
    //Do Not Accepting Code
  }
?>
```